# How can I cache dynamic images in Next app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, caching, next.js

I'm getting response from api that is a list of objects. The object contains property imageUrl, which is a link to to the image. How can I set cache-control to that image?

Comment: you can write proper code to get exact answer

Comment: That wasn't very helpful

Comment: Couple of questions: **1)** Are you using `next/image` component to render your images; **2)** If yes, are you using the Next.js' built-in Image Optimization or a cloud provider's optimization (see [https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#loader](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#loader))?

Answer (score 5):

Add the below code in the "next.config.js" file of your project to cache images for 60 seconds:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    minimumCacheTTL: 60,
  },
}
```

You can change the cache time in secs instead of 60.

Here is thr Next.js official documentation
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#style

Answer (score 0):

The above answer by Naveen didn't work for me.

```
images: {
remotePatterns: [
  {
    protocol: 'https',
    hostname: 'host.com',
    port: '',
    pathname: '/pathname/**',
  },
],
```

},

add the above code to next.config.js (from Nextjs [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image)).

Comment: To help people understand your answer better, please provide some extra information along with the code you shared.